# Adding strikethrough to NSAttributedString in iOS 11 with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, strikethrough

Having some issues getting strikethrough to work. Currently I'm doing the following:

```
theString.addAttributes([
        NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, 
        NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughColor: UIColor.white
    ], range: NSMakeRange(0, 1))
```

It's not showing any sort of strikethrough though. Any ideas? I can't seem to find anything that works.

Comment: Your code is working for me. Though only the first letter is getting the strikethrough given the range you have. Try different colors. Maybe you can't see the white strikethrough if the background is white.

Comment: Ummmm hmmmmmm why can't I see it in my label -_-

Comment: Show more relevant code. I tested in a playground without a label.

Comment: There isn't really anything else relevant, using almost identical code to underline text works perfectly. Does strikethrough maybe only work in a textview and not a label?

Comment: Just used a label in a playground. Still working for me. Maybe a font issue or a colors issue. That's why you need to provide more details.

Comment: Yeah it's working in a playground for me too. Lemme see if maybe it's the font I'm using?

Comment: Hrmmm, seems to be something with TTTAttributedLabel. I got it to work with kTTTStrikeOutAttributeName instead, but I can't set the color that way it seems :/

Answer (score 14):

I use this to strike through a text in Xcode9/iOS11/Swift4 env

```
  let strokeEffect: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue,
        NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughColor: UIColor.red,
    ]

   let strokeString = NSAttributedString(string: "text", attributes: strokeEffect)
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 5.1**

```
let attributedText : NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your Text")
attributedText.addAttributes([
                NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
                NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughColor: UIColor.lightGray,
                NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0)
                ], range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length))
```

Answer (score 4):

swift 4.1

```
attributedText.addAttributes([
NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughStyle:NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughColor:UIColor.black],
range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length))
```

Answer (score 1):

swift 4.2

```
    let mutPricesString : NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
    var attrPrice_1 : NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString()
    var attrPrice_2 : NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString()

    attrPrice_1 = NSAttributedString(string: "14000 KD", attributes:
            [NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
             NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray,
             NSAttributedString.Key.font: ARFont.Regular(fontSize: 15)])

    attrPrice_2 = NSAttributedString(string: " 12460 KD", attributes:
        [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black,
         NSAttributedString.Key.font: ARFont.Semibold(fontSize: 17)])

    mutPricesString.append(attrPrice_1)
    mutPricesString.append(attrPrice_2)
    
    lbl.attributedText = mutPricesString
```

ANSWER :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
func strikethrough(_ text:String) -> NSAttributedString{
        //strikethrough
        let range = (self as NSString).range(of: text)
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:self)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughColor, value: UIColor.gray, range: range)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, value: 2, range: range)
        
        return attributedString
}
```

```
label.attributedText = "Hello world".strikethrough("world")
```

Comment: Don't use hardcoded constants like "2". Use the actual library constant like the other answers do.

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing latest updates. For Swift4, iOS 11.3

```
    attributedText.addAttributes([ 
    NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: 
    NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, 
    NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName: 
    UIColor.black], range: textRange)
```